# How to send SMS masive in Twilio with Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, sms, twilio-api

I would like to know how I can send a message to different numbers. I mean, send SMS as notifications to different numbers in the same String Array. Something like:

```
body: "Hello Word!"
number:["+2222", "+2222", "+2222"]
```

Is it possible to do this with twilio?

It should be possible, if it is possible with mail, how is it done with telephone numbers?

I am using nodeJs and had something like:

**updated code**

```
    const sendBulkMessages = async(req, res) => {
    let messageBody = req.body;
    let numberList = req.body;
    var numbers = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
        numbers.push(JSON.stringify({
            binding_type: 'sms',
            address: numberList[i]
        }))
    }


    const notificationOpts = {
        toBinding: numbers,
        body: messageBody,
    };

    const response = await client.notify
        .services(SERVICE_SID)
        .notifications.create(notificationOpts)
        .then(notification => console.log(notification.sid))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

    console.log(response);

    res.json({
        msg: 'Mensaje enviado correctamente'
    });
}
```

But it tells me an error that I did not send the body, when clearly I do.

Someone could help me? Please

Comment: I can see that you have a `messageBody` argument that is being passed into your `sendBulkMessages` function, but where is that called? Is it possible that the `messageBody` isn't being filled in correctly? Otherwise, your code looks fine.

Comment: @Filnash I have updated the code (in the ask), now I pass it in the body of the request. I don't know what is happening but it keeps giving me the same error "Message body is required" I already read the documentation, I didn't find anything that helped. I set up a message service, etc. I am really lost.

Comment: `req.body` is the entire body of the request, so that's not going to be a text message. What is the request you are making to this endpoint?

Comment: I want to make a post that receives a string array on the request, which receives the phone numbers. And the body of the message. That's what I really want to do, send the same message to different numbers. Like:  post = { numbers: ['+222', '+222'], body: 'Hello'} Can this be done with twilio?

Comment: This may be of interest - https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-notify

Comment: Hello @Alan, I know it's been a while, but I have a question, how can I add a title to the sender of the notification? I mean, when an SMS notification appears, do not say that +64xxx sends it, but rather a name appears. How to give a name to the number assigned by twilio for SMS notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to send these messages via a post request to an Express application. The issue is that you are not extracting the data from the body of the request correctly.

If your `POST` request body is a JSON object that looks like this:

```json
{
  "toBinding": ['+222', '+222'],
  "body": 'Hello'
}
```

Then you will need to make sure you are parsing the body of the request as JSON, normally by adding the [Express body parser JSON middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserjsonoptions), and then extract the data from the request body like this:

```js
let messageBody = req.body.body;
let numberList = req.body.toBinding;
```

Here's the full script:

```js
const sendBulkMessages = async(req, res) => {
    let messageBody = req.body.body;
    let numberList = req.body.toBinding;
    var numbers = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
        numbers.push(JSON.stringify({
            binding_type: 'sms',
            address: numberList[i]
        }))
    }


    const notificationOpts = {
        toBinding: numbers,
        body: messageBody,
    };

    const response = await client.notify
        .services(SERVICE_SID)
        .notifications.create(notificationOpts)
        .then(notification => console.log(notification.sid))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

    console.log(response);

    res.json({
        msg: 'Mensaje enviado correctamente'
    });
}
```

Having inspected [your repo](https://github.com/IzliaB/SendSMSTwilio), it appears that your function was actually correct, but the way you were exporting and requiring functions wasn't.

You can't export functions like this:

```js
 module.exports = sendMessage, sendMessageWhatsapp, sendBulkMessages;
```

That only exports the first function, the others are ignored. So I updated it to this:

```js
module.exports = { sendMessage, sendMessageWhatsapp, sendBulkMessages };
```

This exports an object containing the three functions. Then, when you require the functions, you can't do this:

```js
const sendMessage = require('./message');
const sendMessageWhatsapp = require('./message');
const sendBulkMessages = require('./message');
```

That requires the same function three times. With the update above, you can now do this:

```js
const {
  sendMessage,
  sendBulkMessages,
  sendMessageWhatsapp,
} = require("./message");
```

Comment: I don't understand, although I followed your answer and your explanation keeps giving me the same error. And I even tried other ways and still the same. I uploaded the repository, maybe you see something that I'm not seeing, because I really can't make sense of why it doesn't work, https://github.com/IzliaB/SendSMSTwilio/blob/main/server/message.js

Comment: I can't see where you are sending requests to the `/sendVarios` endpoint. Is that somewhere?

Comment: It looks like you've included your account sid and auth token in that repo, which is a security risk for your account. You should [follow this process to change your auth token now](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them).

Comment: oops! I did not notice

Comment: Good work removing it from the repo, but do make sure you change your auth token too. Now, on your problem, how are you sending the request to your back-end to send multiple messages?

Comment: I think I did not understand the question. But, it goes something like this: In the app.js call the message Routes.js "app.use('/', require('./messageRoute'));" Which in turn calls the "sendBulkMessages" handler in the message.js file which does the post. In postman I make the request to the endpoint.

Comment: OK, what does your request look like in Postman?

Comment: It's like: 
{
    "body": "Testing",
    "toBinding": ["+50489854230", "+50488287591"]
}

Comment: Ok, try `const messageBody = req.body.body;` and `const numberList = req.body.toBinding;`. Whatever you call the property in your request is how you access it from `req.body`. You can also try logging `req.body` to see what is coming into the function, and log `messageBody` and `numberList` to make sure they are being set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your patient. After the suggested changes this was the result, I attach the link with the screenshot of the error that it throws at me: https://github.com/IzliaB/SendSMSTwilio/blob/main/error%20twilio%20sentSMSBucket.png . It's like what I want to do isn't really defined in the twilio api. I took the tutorial on how to do it from this page: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/send-bulk-sms-twilio-node-js.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243006/discussion-between-philnash-and-izlia).